# My dividers change size and move about oddly when the window is resized

Tags: css

Below is the main container, side and card containers for my site.
when I resize the window they move and resize themselves and stack on top of each other, I would like them to stay the same size and just have a horizontal scroll bar.

```
.main {
    width: 75%;
}
.side {
    background-color: #232323;
    border-left: 4px solid #395d9e;
    float: left;
    width: 16%;
    padding: 57px 15px;
    height: 100%;
}
.card {
    float: left;
    background-color: #232323;
    padding: 0 15px;
    margin: 80px 0 0 20px;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 82%;
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: The behavior you describe is "responsive" and is generally considered a good thing. But, it's your page and you should be able to make it do your bidding. To get help, though, you should either include all of your html (if it is small) or a small segment that shows the behavior. Also indicate if you are using any libraries or frameworks that may be affecting behavior. I don't think anyone can help you from seeing just your css.

Comment: Would it be easier if I posted it in a pastebin?

Comment: I'd recommend posting it on jsfiddle.net instead, then including both relevant code here and a link to your fiddle. I hadn't heard of pastebin before but I just looked at it. jsfiddle is a similar site for sharing but is specialized for sharing running html/css/js code. You can create an account and share saved samples of code for free. https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see your relevant html also, but you have a few things going on here.  First, your total for .main, .side and .card total 173%.  This might not matter if .card is inside .main or .side.

Next, consider using the css property `box-sizing:border-box`.  In CSS, width is calculated as the sum of (element width + padding + border + margin).  Using border-box, the padding and border are considered part of the total width.  In other words, for .side, the 16% will include your 15px right and left padding.

Finally, even using border-box, your right and left margins affect total width.  If both .card and .side are located inside .main, you could set your right margin for .card as a percent (e.g. `margin: 80px 0 0 2%;`) and a percentage for the .side element as well.

What is happening here is when you resize your browser window to a small width, the fixed padding and margin can force your elements to float below the others.  Assuming .side and .card are inside .main, they have a total declared width of 98% + 80px.  You would need (if this is the case) a width of 4000px to contain both .side and .card.

Try using box-sizing:border-box for all 3 elements, and use percentage based margin and possibly padding.